# How to solve symbolic equation with double coefficients in matlab?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I have quadratic equation 1/x = 1/(a-x) + 1/(3*a -x)

I want to solve it in matlab:

```
solve('1/x=1/(a-x)+1/(3*a-x)', 'x')
ans =
 (4/3+1/3*7^(1/2))*a
 (4/3-1/3*7^(1/2))*a
```

Is there any way to solve equation with float coefficient? Like

```
ans = 
  2.215250437021530*a
  0.451416229645136*a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apparently](http://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/showthread.php?t=8234), `double(ans)` should convert it for you.

Comment: But I get only error message:

>> double(ans)
??? Error using ==> sym.double at 25
DOUBLE cannot convert the input expression into a double array.
If the input expression contains a symbolic variable, use the VPA function instead.

Comment: What happens if you use the function VPA(ans)?

Answer (score 0):

I used eval() to get a double result from a symbolic expression