# Using the 'solve' function

Tags: matlab, numbers, equation, solver

I would like to solve an equation for x, and i know that there are atleast two solutions,which means that jj will be a vector. I need the largest of those solutions - that is were max(jj) comes into play. However z = max(jj)
will give me the biggest number, but it does not evaluate it. for example z could be = 2*3^4 + 1 . In this form i can't send this "number" to another function  which I want to do. the 'k' is a given number not a variable. (say k=10 or any other number)

```
syms x
eqn = x + (k/6)*(x^2 -1) ==0
jj =  solve(eqn,x)

z = max(jj)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to solve symbolic equation with double coefficients in matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881010/how-to-solve-symbolic-equation-with-double-coefficients-in-matlab) and [how to convert this solve answer to numeric in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16601515/2278029) and [Convert output from symbolic math (sym) to float](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16201050/2278029).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a way to convert from symbolic to numeric form. There is a standard [symbolic toolbox function](http://se.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/double.html?refresh=true) for that: `double`.

`z1=double(z)`

should return the value of the expression in a double format array.