# Equation Interpretation In MATLAB

Tags: matlab

would like to ask for help on how to interpret this equation(Differential) in Matlab Code

```
dC/dt=PC+K2*I-μc*C
```

I have looked at many tutorials on to solve differential equations in matlab and none have been clear to me, according to what i have looked up You can Liken dC/dT to dy/dx ie.

```
dsolve('Dy = PC+K2*I-μc*C','x')
```

In which - PC,K2,I,μc,C.  are all variables

Q1. Am i on the right path?

Q2. Is it possible for me to view the steps(equation) carried out in order to get the answer and how?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you have some typos in your example as it neither depends on x nor on y.

Comment: I am not sure i get what you mean

Comment: Your best bet is to look directly at an example, for instance in http://se.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/dsolve.html

Answer (score 1):

To use dsolve on your system start by looking at some examples in the [documentation](http://se.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/dsolve.html?refresh=true)

For your system a solution would be

```
syms PC K2 muc I C(t)
dsolve(diff(C) == PC + K2*I - muc*C)
```

Comment: Thank You for your input, really appreciate. i ran the code in matlab substituting the variables, `syms PC K2 muc I C(t)
dsolve(diff(C) == 5 + 4*6 - 7*3)` and got this `C9 + 8*t` now i don't know what to make of it, as it went straight on to the answer, is there a way in which the code can be tweaked that it shows the steps it followed while solving the equation. Thanks again.

Comment: @KennethIwuchukwu You might want to check out some of the examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28610908/using-the-solve-function/28616858#28616858)

Comment: Alright but will it be possible to solve it symbolically using python ? If yes could you tell me how? Thanks.

Comment: @KennethIwuchukwu You can try [sympy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) - I am not familiar with it though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that in Matlab (it's strengths are  numeric calculations and not symbolic).

If i were to give a tip i would head over to [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/DifferentialEquations.html) (see the examples). It can show step by step solutions to simple equations. I suppose you would find similar features in Mathematica.